# 'imports' statement must precede any declarations

Tags: vb.net, import, declaration

```
    module module1
    imports System.Collections.Generic
    imports System.Io
        sub main()



            dim subject as string
            dim topic(5) as string
            dim question(5) as string
            dim foundfile as List
            dim directory as string

            console.writeline("enter the subject your revising")
            subject=console.readline()

            directory="C:\Users\Zak\Documents\revisionhog\subjects\physics\imaging"

            For each file as String In IO.directory.Getfiles(directory, "*.pdf", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                foundfile.add(file)

            Next


            for x = 0 to 5
                console.writeline(foundFile)
            next

        end sub
end module
```

tyring to add file that i have found after a search to a list of strings.
i thought that i had placed import before declarations???
help???

Comment: You have `module` before `imports`. What does the error message **clearly** tell you?

Comment: C# `using` statements can appear inside a type definition. The same is not true of VB `Imports` statements. That may be the source of some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
imports System.Collections.Generic
imports System.Io

module module1
        sub main()



        dim subject as string
        dim topic(5) as string
        dim question(5) as string
        dim foundfile as List
        dim directory as string

        console.writeline("enter the subject your revising")
        subject=console.readline()

        directory="C:\Users\Zak\Documents\revisionhog\subjects\physics\imaging"

        For each file as String In IO.directory.Getfiles(directory, "*.pdf", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            foundfile.add(file)

        Next


        for x = 0 to 5
            console.writeline(foundFile)
        next

    end sub
end module
```

The imports come first, like you mentioned. This fixes the problem with the `import` statements, but your question is a bit unclear. If you have other issues, please state those clearly.

Comment: Feeding these types of questions are discouraged here, we help with specific programming issues, not something that clearly can be fixed with a quick Google search. Lack of research on the OP...

Comment: i would like to create a program that asks for a subject of learning eg 'physics' then loads all files i have saved in a pre-existing directory by replacing 'physics' in the path with whichever subject they choose.